# ES6 classes don't work on Chrome 47

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Google Chrome claims to support ES6 classes since version 42, but it gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class(…)` when i run the simple code from below in the console:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
```

Firefox also doesn't work. Microsoft Edge works just fine. Is this normal?

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you in "use strict" mode?

> ES6 classes solve this by providing JavaScript a clean, standardized syntax for classes. This new syntax is available in Chrome 42 for JavaScript written in strict mode.

Comment: @VSG24 I don't have any flags enabled and `(function() { "use strict"; return class Polygon { } })()` worked fine for me in Chrome 47. Are you sure your `"use strict;" declaration is placed correctly? Are you using an older version of Chrome?

Comment: @apsillers I was declaring `"use strict";` in the wrong place. it works now.