# instantiating an es6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use es6 to make a chatroom connection class. I am using rabbitmq/STOMP to push the exchange data to subscribers. The code I am using had worked in es5 style, but I was hardcoding the exchange name. I am using webpack/babel to transpile this code back to es5 in a file called `chat.bundle.js` but when I run:

`var chatRoom = new ChatRoom('thisExchange');`

The console logs: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ChatRoom is not defined`

I am instantiating the class `ChatRoom` after the bundle file is loaded (below this script tag for the bundle).

I know probably the `load()` function will not work... I am new to es6 classes and not sure how to get window.load to work but this is a separate issue. For now I just want to be able to instantiate this class by providing the argument of the `exchangeName` and then move on to new errors after this.

Here is my terribly written es6 class:

```
// Use SockJS
Stomp.WebSocketClass = SockJS;
// Connection parameters
var mq_username = "guest",
mq_password = "guest",
mq_vhost    = "/",
mq_url      = 'http://localhost:15674/stomp',
mq_queue    = "/exchange/${this.exchange}";
var output;
var client = Stomp.client(mq_url);

class ChatRoom {
    constructor(exchange){
        this._exchange=exchange;
    }
    get exchange(){
        return this._exchange;
    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.exchange}`
    }

    on_connect() {
    output.innerHTML += 'Connected to RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp<br />';
    console.log(client);
    client.subscribe(mq_queue, on_message);
}

// This will be called upon a connection error
    on_connect_error() {
        output.innerHTML += 'Connection failed!<br />';
    }

// This will be called upon arrival of a message
on_message(m) {
    console.log('message received');
    console.log(m);
    output.innerHTML += m.body + '<br />';
}

load(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        window.onload =  () => {
            // Fetch output panel
            output = document.getElementById("output");

            // Connect
            client.connect(
                self.mq_username,
                self.mq_password,
                self.on_connect,
                self.on_connect_error,
                self.mq_vhost
            );
        }
    });
}


}
```

In my html file, the script tags are structured as follow:

```
<script src="static/chat.bundle.js"></script>
<script>var chatRoom=new ChatRoom('soccer@newark');</script>
```

Webpack builds successfully and does not complain about the syntax of the es6 file for the chat bundle as shown above.

Comment: It may be that your class is never defined. Are you in "use strict" mode? If not this may have the same answer as the following post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231445/es6-classes-dont-work-on-chrome-47

Comment: Some hints: Is the chat.bundle.js file correctly created (without any errors) ? When do you do `var chatRoom = new ChatRoom('thisExchange');` ? Check where & when you access `output`

Comment: I added a couple more lines frmo the HTML file where the script tags are included. there dont seem to be any errors in the bundle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, module bundlers such as webpack don't expose module locals.
If you want to export your class `ChatRoom` as public API, add `module.exports` expression at the end of your file

```
module.exports = ChatRoom;
```

> *NB* You may want to use `export default ChatRoom` instead of `module.exports`. But be aware that Babel since 6.0 version exports default under the `default` key rather than entire export. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505992/babel-6-changes-how-it-exports-default) for more information.

But this is not enough. You also need setup Webpack to create a library from your code. Add the following into your webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    library: 'ChatRoom',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

See [webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) for more details